# Pandas split column iterate over each item to two new columns of pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below, but simplified, it could be any variation of random values, not just items one, two, three,  etc

[image]

Then i need to iterate through the items in the ID column and create new pairs of each

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['three', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'three', 'one'] , 
                'ID2':['two', 'one', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'three']}))
```

[image]

Not really sure how to accomplish this, and i understand the df will be very large. hopefully someone has an efficient method.

EDIT: by pair of each, if you cant see from the images, I mean

In the example:

```
A|B|C
```

I have three items, so I want to create new rows of each unique pair, so it would be

```
ID1     ID2
A        B
A        C
B        A
B        C
C        A
C        B
```

Perhaps this is more clear?

Comment: not clear what you mean by "create new pairs of each"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear if you want permutations or  combinations but this code works the same -- you might just have to swap the `permutations` for `combinations` depending.

What we first want to do is take the dataframe and split on the | symbol, then we calculate every combination/permutation of this with the itertools module. See the code for how this works.

```py
import itertools

def split_and_combine(x):
    # split the items on the '|' character
    split_items = x.split('|')
    
    # create permutations/combinations
    # the 2 means calculate pairs
    # change 'permutations' to 'combinations' if needed
    combined = itertools.permutations(split_items, 2)
    
    # return the result as a list
    return list(combined)
    
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(split_and_combine)
```

This gives us...

```
                                                                                 ID
0  [(three, two), (three, one), (two, three), (two, one), (one, three), (one, two)]
1                                                          [(two, one), (one, two)]
2                                                      [(three, two), (two, three)]
3                                                      [(three, one), (one, three)]
```

Now we need to split these lists apart and put each part as a new row. This we put into a new dataframe.

```py
df = df.explode('ID')
```

`df` is now equal to...

```
             ID
0  (three, two)
0  (three, one)
0  (two, three)
0    (two, one)
0  (one, three)
0    (one, two)
1    (two, one)
1    (one, two)
2  (three, two)
2  (two, three)
3  (three, one)
3  (one, three)
```

Now we take each part of the tuple and put it into two separate columns.

```py
df['first'] = df['ID'].str[0]
df['second'] = df['ID'].str[1]
```

The final result is tidied up,

```py
result = df.drop('ID', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`result` is....

```
    first second
0   three    two
1   three    one
2     two  three
3     two    one
4     one  three
5     one    two
6     two    one
7     one    two
8   three    two
9     two  three
10  three    one
11    one  three
```

Comment: That's seems to be what i was trying to do. Thank you